# Zabbix server running not running. Value no in zabbix dashboard on Centos7

Tags: linux, zabbix

What should I do, I have set up everything for what I thought would be a wonderful well running zabbix server and now it is not running on the final step. I cannot figure out what went wrong. How can I fix this? this is my first time, please help thanks  :)[image]

```
?php
// Zabbix GUI configuration file.

$DB['TYPE']                             = 'MYSQL';
$DB['SERVER']                   = 'localhost';
$DB['PORT']                             = '0';
$DB['DATABASE']                 = 'zabbix';
$DB['USER']                             = 'zabbix';
$DB['PASSWORD']                 = 'zabbix_db_pass';

// Schema name. Used for PostgreSQL.
$DB['SCHEMA']                   = '';

// Used for TLS connection.
$DB['ENCRYPTION']               = false;
$DB['KEY_FILE']                 = '';
$DB['CERT_FILE']                = '';
$DB['CA_FILE']                  = '';
$DB['VERIFY_HOST']              = false;
$DB['CIPHER_LIST']              = '';

// Use IEEE754 compatible value range for 64-bit Numeric (float) history values.
"/etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php" 47L, 1484C

///////zabix.conf.php starts here

// Use IEEE754 compatible value range for 64-bit Numeric (float) history values.
// This option is enabled by default for new Zabbix installations.
// For upgraded installations, please read database upgrade notes before enabling this$
$DB['DOUBLE_IEEE754']   = true;

$ZBX_SERVER                             = 'localhost';
$ZBX_SERVER_PORT                = '10051';
$ZBX_SERVER_NAME                = '';

$IMAGE_FORMAT_DEFAULT   = IMAGE_FORMAT_PNG;

// Uncomment this block only if you are using Elasticsearch.
// Elasticsearch url (can be string if same url is used for all types).
//$HISTORY['url'] = [
// 'uint' => 'http://localhost:9200',
// 'text' => 'http://localhost:9200'
//];
```

I also noticed this little message in firewall status:

```
firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-11-22 13:14:25 EST; 2h 5min ago
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)
 Main PID: 767 (firewalld)
    Tasks: 2
   CGroup: /system.slice/firewalld.service
```

it seems like there is just so much going on in my server and I do not know where to edit it. Can anyone give me some help on finding a guide compatible with CentOS Linux release 7.9,2009 (core)

Comment: maybe you have to start the server

Comment: I am pretty sure the server is enabled. but if u want to send me some commands. that would be great.

Comment: google `zabbix server start stop`

Comment: You checked the status of the firewall, but not the status of `zabbix-server`? Do that first. If it's not running, start it. If it still doesn't work, check logfiles for errors.

Comment: I restarted it and started it again then checked status. The server is still not running. I just do not get it. If someone can give me a guide that is compatible with my version of CentOS 7 then that would be great.

Comment: CentOS Linux release 7.9,2009 (core)

Comment: What instructions have you been following so far? I found https://www.zabbix.com/download?zabbix=5.0&os_distribution=red_hat_enterprise_linux&os_version=8&db=mysql as one example; note the choice for Zabbix version. It seems like your post could use a little formatting help as well. Click the question mark icon towards the upper right part of the editing box, and/or see https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help for editing help.

Comment: You need to make sure that the zabbix server is running.  I believe the EPEL package has it as `systemctl status zabbix-server.service`

Answer (score 0):

If you've gotten to the end the [Download and install Zabbix instructions](https://www.zabbix.com/download?zabbix=5.0&os_distribution=centos&os_version=7&db=mysql&ws=apache) and the services aren't running, it seems worth it to try the "Start Zabbix server and agent processes" commands:

```bsh
systemctl restart zabbix-server zabbix-agent httpd php-fpm
systemctl enable zabbix-server zabbix-agent httpd php-fpm
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your zabbix server process is running : `ps -ef | grep -i zabb` from your zabbix-server console (process = `zabbix_server`).

Also make sure you have zabbix-agent running on that very same server (process = `zabbix_agentd`).